# Divide text field input by set number, show result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I have a text field that I need to divide by certain inputs. I've tried using the code below but I am running in to issues. It does not take the decimal point in to account, and will return 0 if you use a decimal.

```
<input id="number" type="text"> ÷ 3.181818<br />
Your output is: <div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//obtain reference to number html element
var number = document.getElementById('number');

//obtain reference to output html element
var output = document.getElementById('output');

//what you want to divide to
var division = '3.181818'; // can't be 0, or the world will explode

//add an eventlistener to the change event on the number element
number.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

  //get the value from the input
  var val = parseFloat(number.value);

  //check if it is a nan
  if(!isNaN(val)) {

     //round it to 0 digits
     output.innerHTML = (val / division).toFixed(0) + "";
  } else {
     output.innerHTML = 'that\'s not a number!';
  }
});
</script>
```

So for example if someone inputs their sensitivity in the text box as `1.2`, it would then do `1.2 / 3.181818 = 0.37714287869`

`0.37714287869` being their new sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `toFixed` and set `div` as a float `3.181818`:

```js
//obtain reference to number html element
var number = document.getElementById('number');

//obtain reference to output html element
var output = document.getElementById('output');

//what you want to divide to
var division = 3.181818; // can't be 0, or the world will explode

//add an eventlistener to the change event on the number element
number.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

  //get the value from the input
  var val = parseFloat(number.value);

  //check if it is a nan
  if (!isNaN(val)) {

    output.innerHTML = val / division;
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = 'that\'s not a number!';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="number" type="text"> ÷ 3.181818<br /> Your output is:
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: wow, such a simple fix. Thank you so much!

Would there be any way to remove some of the numbers towards the end of the result? 

For example the answer being 0.37714287869 would only need to be 0.377?

Comment: @dekl0l That's where you would use `toFixed()`, check out how it works